# programming python number in python program 3.6 version

Tags: python, numbers, code-reuse

Below is my code:

```
Number = input("write your number: ")

if tall.isdigit():
    print("The number is integer")
else:
    print("The number is a floating point")
```

How does the python program understand that 4.0 is not the a floating point ex 4.0 as 4 is not different mathematic, with another case how can python make mathamtic calculation from 4.0 to 4 and the answer will be in console the number is integer?

Comment: input returns a string in python 3, and `.isdigit()` is a string method so it 'works' (but not for negative integers, since `'-'` is not a digit; and all other non-digit characters also not necessarily valid floats of course)

Comment: what kind of answer should this question get?  A tutorial on strings and other types and python?